# jquery disable dropdown items based on changing another dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have 2 dropdowns, 'Level' and 'Guards'

```
Level
-----
1
2
3
etc

Guards
-----
1
2
3
etc
```

I want to disable every option in Guards that is greater than the value of Level.

So if Level 2 is highlighted, the only options in Guards that will be available is 1 and 2.

I have the basics of change() already, just unsure how to do this part

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and worked. Try it out

```
$(document).on('change', '#drop_down_1', function() {
   var currVal = $(this).val();

   $('#drop_down_2 option').each(function() {
      //enable everything else
      $(this).attr('disabled', false);

      var secondVal = $(this).val();
      if (secondVal > currVal) {
         $('#drop_down_2 option[value='+secondVal+']').attr('disabled', true);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i<3;i++) {
if (level > i) {
guard(i)=disabled;
}
}
```

This would be the logic for that statement.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var levelsArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $levels = $('#Levels'),
    $gaurds = $('#Gaurds');

$levels.html('<option value="0">--Select a Level--</option>');
$gaurds.html('<option value="0">--Select Gaurds--</option>');

var html='';
for(var i=0;i< levelsArray.length ;i++) {
    html += opt ='<option value="'+ levelsArray[i] +'">'+levelsArray[i] +'</option>'
}

$levels.append(html);
$gaurds.append(html);

$levels.on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $('option', $gaurds).attr('disabled', false);
    if(value !== 0) {
        $('option:gt('+ value+ ')', $gaurds).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cSvX6/)**